# How to convert date column in dataframe from numbers to formatted text? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, calculated-columns

I have a column `dt["startDateEST"]` that ouputs as:

```
0    2021-07-27 21:46:00-04:00
1    2021-07-27 21:46:00-04:00
2    2021-07-27 19:06:00-04:00
3    2021-07-27 19:06:00-04:00
4    2021-07-27 19:11:00-04:00
                ...           
79   2021-07-27 19:11:00-04:00
80   2021-07-27 19:11:00-04:00
81   2021-07-27 19:11:00-04:00
82   2021-07-27 19:11:00-04:00
83   2021-07-27 19:06:00-04:00
Name: startDateEST, Length: 84, dtype: datetime64[ns, America/New_York]
```

I'm trying to create a new column `dt["startDateEST_Long"]` that is `dt["startDateEST"]` converted to word format as:

```
0    Jul 27, 2021, 9:46 PM
1    Jul 27, 2021, 9:46 PM
2    Jul 27, 2021, 7:06 PM
3    Jul 27, 2021, 7:06 PM
4    Jul 27, 2021, 7:11 PM
             etc...
```

I've tried different versions of datetime functions and converting to a string object (.tolist)/parsing through but can't anything to work or run without a Series/attribute error. Please help, thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create some sample data:

```
dates = pd.date_range("2021-07-27", periods=48, freq="H").tz_localize("America/New_York")
```

Then fill the DataFrame

```
dt = pd.DataFrame({"startDateEST": dates})
```

Have a look at python datetime formatting strings and format accordingly

```
dt["startDateEST_Long"] = dt["startDateEST"].dt.strftime('%b %d, %Y, %I:%M%p')
```

```
dt.head()
```

```
0 2021-07-27 00:00:00-04:00  Jul 27, 2021, 12:00AM
1 2021-07-27 01:00:00-04:00  Jul 27, 2021, 01:00AM
2 2021-07-27 02:00:00-04:00  Jul 27, 2021, 02:00AM
3 2021-07-27 03:00:00-04:00  Jul 27, 2021, 03:00AM
4 2021-07-27 04:00:00-04:00  Jul 27, 2021, 04:00AM
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you! I had the wrong parameters for my `dt.strftime`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it a datetime first, then use `strftime` to convert to a string in the required format.  You can find the options [here](https://strftime.org/).  Worth noting that a non-zero padded hour `%-I` only works on certain operating systems, hence the tendency to just use `%I` which will zero pad the hour

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'startDateEST':[
        '2021-07-27 21:46:00-04:00',
        '2021-07-27 19:11:00-04:00'
    ]
})


df['startDateEST_Long'] = df.startDateEST.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime(format='%b %d, %Y, %I:%M %p'))

print(df)
```

Output

```
                startDateEST       startDateEST_Long
0  2021-07-27 21:46:00-04:00  Jul 27, 2021, 09:46 PM
1  2021-07-27 19:11:00-04:00  Jul 27, 2021, 07:11 PM
```